# How can we create a string type with prefix/suffix word in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a type like this:

```
type State = 'state1' | 'state2' | 'state3';
```

Now I want to define another type **DefaultState** like below code but don't want to write 'state[X]' manually. It should automatically map all possible state with string `-default` :-

```
type DefaultState = 'state1-default' | 'state2-default' | 'state3-default';
type AllState = State | DefaultState;

const s1: AllState = 'state1';
const s2: AllState = 'state2';
const s3: AllState = 'state1-default';

// All these values for s1, s2, s3 should be valid.
```

Do we have anything in typescript upto v4.0.0-beta or any version for this?

Comment: That said, you could always resort to using T4 to generate repetitive code - provided you use MSBuild in your build process.

Comment: There is suggestion/issue open https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6579. Once this resolved, should be able to achieve easily.

Comment: @DeepakDixit I deleted my suggestion because I found out it isn't supported by tsc.

Answer (score 0):

When using typescript 4 is an option for you, you can use [Template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html):

```
type DefaultState = `${State}-default`
```

See [playground code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAysCGxoF4oCIDOCkEY1QB90tEIAmfIzbCAZjQFgAoUSKAEQgDN4BXAG2BxSUVAAMAJAG9hSAL4BaACbc+gsc2YBjAPYA7LFHgAuDqoFCao4jRzLzgxk10HgUAEanOPC7JQ3SMnsfRyA)